# How to change clip-path value in CSS rule using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

how to change
 #clip-home.open clip-path Value

```
#clip-home {
  z-index: 2;
  clip-path: circle(2em);
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
#clip-home.open {
  background-color: #45a26f;
  clip-path: circle(300px);
}
```

Comment: show you js code

Comment: `document.querySelector("#clip-home.open").style.clipPath =
    "circle(200em)";`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("clip-home").style.clipPath = "circle(10px)"
```

Follows a full working code:

```js
document.getElementById("clip-home").style.clipPath = "circle(10px)"
```

```css
#clip-home {
  z-index: 2;
  clip-path: circle(2em);
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
#clip-home.open {
  background-color: #45a26f;
  clip-path: circle(300px);
}
```

```html
<div id="clip-home"></div>
```

Comment: only change the .open clip-path value

Comment: try this but it change the #clip-home value`document.getElementById("clip-home").style.clipPath = "circle(10px)"`

Comment: @Alipe I did not understand your question.

Comment: `#clip-home.open {
  background-color: #45a26f;
  clip-path: circle(300px);
}` this value i want to change

Comment: Changing the styles in the javascript it will be applied to the element and not according to the css. The only think you can do is, in the moment you want to change the style in the javascript, you check if the element has the class open or not and then aplying a style according to it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('clip-home').style.clipPath = 'circle(100px)'
```